# Texlive 2015 problem - cannot find 'article.cls'

Tags: errors, texlive, mac

**EDIT: This turned out to be a problem due to having forgotten to update the distribution in the Texpad editor preferences!**

I have just updated from TexLive 2014 to 2015 using the full MacTeX-2015 Distribution on Yosemite which I downloaded and installed yesterday. Upon compiling a simple new document with pdflatex

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

I get an error message:

```
/usr/texbin/pdflatex -file-line-error -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 -output-directory=/Users/xyz/    Desktop/.texpadtmp test.tex

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.

! LaTeX Error: File `article.cls' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)

Enter file name: 
./test.tex:2: Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.2 ^^M

./test.tex:2:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on /Users/xyz/Desktop/.texpadtmp/test.log.
```

Needless to say that the file article.cls sits happily at

```
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
```

I have tried

```
sudo -H mktexlsr
```

and the result looks OK to me:

```
mktexlsr: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-config/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Updating /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Done.
```

and the output from

```
kpsepath tex | sed 's/:/\n/g'
```

also looks fine as far as I can tell:

```
    .n/Users/xyz/Library/texlive/2015/texmf-config/tex/kpsewhich//n/Users/xyz/Library/texlive/2015/texmf-var/tex/kpsewhich//n/Users/xyz/Library/texmf/tex/kpsewhich//n!!/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-config/tex/kpsewhich//n!!/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/tex/kpsewhich//n!!/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/kpsewhich//n!!/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/kpsewhich//n/Users/xyz/Library/texlive/2015/texmf-config/tex/generic//n/Users/xyz/Library/texlive/2015/texmf-var/tex/generic//n/Users/xyz/Library/texmf/tex/generic//n!!/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-config/tex/generic//n!!/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/tex/generic//n!!/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/generic//n!!/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic//n/Users/xyz/Library/texlive/2015/texmf-config/tex///n/Users/xyz/Library/texlive/2015/texmf-var/tex///n/Users/xyz/Library/texmf/tex///n!!/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-config/tex///n!!/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/tex///n!!/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex///n!!/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex///
```

When I switch back to the 2014 distro all seems to be working OK...

I'm at a loss - any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: exactly what is `/usr/texbin` pointing to? You might ber able to test is via `ls -l /usr/texbin` in a terminal

Comment: It outputs: `lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  42  8 Sep 16:03 /usr/texbin -> /Library/TeX/Distributions/Programs/texbin`

Comment: Do the same thing with `/Library/TeX/Distributions/Programs/texbin` we are looking for the end of these `->` chains

Comment: `/Library/TeX/Distributions/Programs/texbin -> ../.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/texbin`

Comment: Hmm, our search will of course be wrong if you have changed the system back to TL14. How exactly did you do to change back to TL14?

Comment: I use the tool in the Systems Preferences pane that comes with MacTeX. I can revert backwards and forward between the two - every time I select the 2014 distro all is fine but when I select the 2015 distro it stops working. The outputs I sent earlier where for the 2015 setting. Thanks for trying to help me btw

Comment: Please switch to TL15, and in a **new** terminal run `kpsewhich article.cls` and `which latex`

Comment: I get `/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls` and `/Library/TeX/texbin/latex` respectively

Comment: Now test your test doc via `pdflatex test.tex` or what ever name you have given it.

Comment: What happens if you switch in the terminal to the folder of your test.tex and simply call pdflatex test?

Comment: This is strange. If I do this it all works fine and it produces pdf output

Comment: Restart your editor to see if it will also run in the editor

Comment: Oh dear, I got it - such a stupid mistake, I'm really sorry for this. I'm using Texpad and in the preferences for the editor it had selected the 2014 distro explicitly rather than the generic path. I changed this and restarted Texpad and all is fine again now.

Comment: I'm really stupid, sorry for wasting your time with this!

Comment: Hey, now we know yet another thing we need users to check when debugging things like this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was due to a misconfigured front-end.